# Maven deploy plugin disable redeployment

Tags: maven, artifactory

Is it possible to disable redeployment just from pom level via deployment plugin configuration?

Im trying to prevent redeployment of few artifacts in artifactory but dont want to set this globaly (i know it should be dole globaly, but im just a user of that artifactory and it is not up to me to decide).
Thats why i was wondering if it is posible to configure my artifacts poms to fail if deployment would in fact mean redeployment of non SNAPSHOT version.

Maven used: 3.6.1

Answer (score 0):

There is no parameter for [`deploy:deploy`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/deploy-mojo.html) to achieve this. There are two workarounds to prevent unintentional deploying at least:

#### 1. `deploy:deploy <skip>`

```xml
    <properties>
        <skipDeploy>true</skipDeploy>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0-M1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <skip>${skipDeploy}</skip>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

Deploy with:

```bash
mvn deploy -DskipDeploy=false
```

#### 2. Deploy to local TEMP by default, use profile to really deploy

```xml
    <distributionManagement>
        <repository>
            <uniqueVersion>false</uniqueVersion>
            <id>local-dummy-repo</id>
            <name>local dummy repository to prevent unintentional re-deploying</name>
            <url>file://${env.TEMP}/maven-dummy-repo</url>
            <layout>default</layout>
        </repository>
    </distributionManagement>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>deploy</id>
            <distributionManagement>
                <repository>
                    <uniqueVersion>false</uniqueVersion>
                    <id>repo</id>
                    <name>real repository</name>
                    <url>scheme://authority/path</url>
                    <layout>default</layout>
                </repository>
            </distributionManagement>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
```

Deploy with:

```bash
mvn deploy -Pdeploy
```

Comment: considering the fact that deployment is via Jenkins job which have simple command. it is not quite what im trying to do. But thanks for proposal. Probably will have to go with some sort of a script.

Comment: @T.G What exactly do you mean by „_Jenkins job which have simple command_“ The Maven build step has a _Goals and Options_ field and each Jenkins job/project can be parameterized by activating _Configuration_ → _General_ → _This build is parameterized_, too.